# Django REST Framework - Change ID Format

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am currently playing around with Django + Django REST Framework to build an API layer. A question I was curious about is if it's possible to change the id layout. Currently my model looks something like this:

```
class Thing(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ThingContainer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    things = models.ManyToManyField(Thing)
```

This means that DRF (using ModelViewSet and ModelSerializer) automatically generates API endpoints like `/things/1` or `/thing_containers/2`.

I was wondering if there is a neat trick to change the format of the outward-facing ID. So instead of `/things/1` it would be `/things/YXBwOi8vdGhpbmcvMQ==` which is the `base64` encoding of `app://things/1`.

I am aware that I could change the key of the model itself into a CharField and enforce that format on the DB level. However that comes with its own set of performance issues and other caveats.

Answer (score 0):

You should override method **retrieve** in viewset. And fix url in urlpatterns